# Why did Microsoft kill "English Query" on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Given the popularity of the natural language user interface [Siri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siri_%28software%29), which was acquired by Apple for $200 million, I've wondered if anyone knows why Microsoft killed ["English Query" on SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa198281%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason it was dropped was because of lack of use. [This is confirmed in the MS response to a Customer asking if it could be re-instated](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/718280/english-query).

> **Posted by Microsoft on 1/13/2012 at 1:37 PM**
>
> English Query feature when introduced in SQL Server was not a popular
>   feature and we didn't find lot of customers using it. So it was
>   eventually removed from the product. We have no plans to invest in
>   such technology so I am resolving this as "won't fix". You can look at
>   the Semantic Search feature in SQL Server 2012 to see if that meets
>   your needs.

Answer (score 2):

See [this brief article](http://www.infoq.com/news/English-Query-Discontinued):

> Microsoft hasn't said much as to why English Query was [discontinued]. One
>   could speculate that it may be due to lack of interest or an inability
>   to provide accurate translations.

Answer (score 0):

It's back! ;-)

Microsoft has announced a private preview of Copilot for SQL Azure, which offers a natural language for SQL conversion and self-help for database administration.

https://www.infoq.com/news/2024/03/sql-azure-copilot-preview/